# Как переписать цикл for на цикл do while?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Есть код, который считает элементы с четными номерами и выводит их произведение. Как мне переписать его используя ТОЛЬКО цикл do..while?

```
int array[100];
int len;
int multi = 1;

cout << "Введите длину массива = ";
cin >> len;
cout << "Введите значения массива = ";
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    cin >> array[i];
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        multi *= array[i];
    }
}
cout << "Произведение элементов с парными номерами = " << multi << endl;
```

Comment: Прочитать базовую документацию C или C++ по этому циклу, понять как он работает и написать.

Comment: На `while() {...}` легко, а вот на `do { ... } while(...);` без дополнительного `if (...)` перед ним в общем случае  не получится

Comment: На while я знаю как написать, а вот на do while как раз нет. Дополнительные if можно использовать, мне просто главное увидеть где-то нормальный предмет как переписать это в do while, потому что пока что не совсем мне ясно(

Comment: @denvud все тоже самое что и с `while` только перед `do ... while` проверку нужно сделать на `len > 0` думаю если почитать про цикл `do ... while` будет понятно почему так.

Comment: а шаг, к примеру for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) первым записывать? 
То есть, do { i = size - 1; i--; // условие // } while (i >= 0)?

Comment: @denvud, раз вам подобные темы (как одно смоделировать другим) нравятся, то задумайтесь над тем, что самой общей управляющей структурой является **`while () { ... }`**. Используя **только ее**  (с дополнительными переменными, конечно) можно моделировать все остальные, используемые в структурном программировании (даже if-then-else)

Answer (score 2):

Цикл `for` можно переписать на `while` так :

```
for ( A ; B ; C )
  D ;

{ A ;
  while ( B ) {
    D ;
continu :
    C ; } }
```

А если вам нужно конкретно `do while` то нужно вручную делать сначала сравнение.

```
{ A ;
  if ( B ) {
    do {
      D ;
continu :
      C ; 
    } while ( B ) ; } }
```

ваш пример :

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    cin >> array[i];
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        multi *= array[i];
    }
}
```

используем `do while` :

```
{ int i = 0;
  if ( i < len ) {
    do {
      cin >> array[i];
      if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
      {
        multi *= array[i];
      }
continu :
      i ++ ;
    } while ( i < len ) ; } }
```

---

*Метка **conitinu :** потребуется, если в цикле использовалась команда **continue ;**. Вместо неё нужно делать **goto continu ;** .*

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
        i++;
        ///
    } while (i < len)
```